# Unable to perform TFS Build on a FIPS enabled system

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild, fips

I'm working on a system with FIPS enabled, disabling is not an option.  I was able to get a local build to work following tips to add the FIPS enabled=false flag to the MS build config files and the devenv config files on my build server and local workstation for VS2013 & 2015.
However, I'm still receiving the exception message:  This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.  Exception stack trace:  at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor() error.
How do I get past this error for TFS Builds?
I did read that there was an issue with SHA256Managed, is there a way to have it use one of the other two methods that are FIPS compliant?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or new tasks based build? When did you get the exception message, ran MSBuild or TFS Build?

Comment: Using TFS 2015 on Prem.  XAML build of a sample simple calc app.  The exception is persistent on TFS Builds.  Was able to resolve issue with MSBuild per the tips.

Comment: By default, XAML build calls MSBuild to build the project. Try to login your build agent machine and use MSBuild command line to build the project to  check the result. If MSBuild command line on build agent machine can build the project, then TFS should also have a successful build.

Comment: When I perform an MSBuild via the command line it is successful.  The command used was msbuild.exe SimpleCalculator.csproj /t:rebuild.  Very simple.  Executed it from where the proj file was located.  However, when I perform another build using XAML and the default build process template it fails.  I have output from both builds that I can send if that helps.

Comment: What's the account your configure on build controller? Can you try with the same account that you run msbuild manually?

Comment: I'm using a domain account for the build service.  I logged into the build server with that account, ran msbuild manually via the command line and it was successful.  When I ran a TFS build using the XAML build services I get the error.